# SQLAlchemy with Postgres: Property returning JSONElement instead of result

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Goal: Object has two attributes: First attribute points to a Python list backed by a JSON array. Second attribute points to a specific index in that first attribute's list.

Problem: Second attribute listed above currently doesn't work.

Background: SQLAlchemy attribute with a [`TypeDecorator`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html#sqlalchemy.types.TypeDecorator) derived from [`JSONB`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSONB) works as expected. When trying to index the attribute (extract the second value in the array, for instance), I get a [`JSONElement`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSONElement) (derived from [`BinaryExpression`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.BinaryExpression)) instead of an actual result.

Attributes in my class are defined as follows:

```
class MyClass...
    values_to_hold = Column(MyArr)

MyClass.second_val_in_arr = MyClass.values_to_hold[1]
```

`second_val_in_arr` returns a `JSONElement` instead of the result as expected. Explicitly adding [`astext`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSONElement.astext) (`MyClass.values_to_hold[1].astext`) does not help either.

If I set:

```
MyClass.second_val_in_arr = MyClass.values_to_hold
```

then `second_val_in_arr` returns the actual array as expected. But if I try to perform an index operation on the array (as above), then it suddenly returns a `JSONElement`.

Additional info:

`MyArr` is a `TypeDecorator` as below:

```
class MyArr(TypeDecorator):
    impl = JSONB

    def coerce_compared_value(self, op, value):
        return self.impl.coerce_compared_value(op, value)

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value:
            return list(value)
        else:
            return list()
```

(Note that `coerce_compared_value` is explicitly overridden because of the special logic required for JSON as per the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html#sqlalchemy.types.TypeDecorator)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment

```
MyClass.second_val_in_arr = MyClass.values_to_hold[1]
```

will just add the `JSONElement` as a regular attribute to the class. SQLAlchemy will not treat it in any special way, so instances of that class will look the attribute up from the class, resulting in the original `JSONElement`. Instead define a [hybrid attribute](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html):

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

class MyClass(...):

    values_to_hold = Column(MyArr)

    @hybrid_property
    def second_val_in_arr(self):
        return self.values_to_hold[1]
```

The hybrid will act as `JSONElement`/`BinaryExpression` in query context, when accessed through the class. It will return the 2nd item in `values_to_hold` when accessed on an instance of the class.